# How we can click on buttons which is inside in Process Flow control in SAPUI5?

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori

I have added two buttons(Approve, Reject) in Process Flow node. But I am not able to click on that buttons.

Can anyone help on this, How we can click on that buttons?

[sap.suite.ui.commons.sample.ProcessFlow](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/entity/sap.suite.ui.commons.ProcessFlow/sample/sap.suite.ui.commons.sample.ProcessFlow)

[ProcessFlow](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.suite.ui.commons.ProcessFlow)

**Code**

```xml
<ProcessFlow id="processflow1" scrollable="false" nodePress="onNodePress" foldedCorners="true" nodes="{/nodes}" lanes="{/lanes}">
    <nodes>
        <ProcessFlowNode id="processflownode1" laneId="{lane}" nodeId="{id}"
                         title="{title}" titleAbbreviation="{titleAbbreviation}"
                         children="{children}" state="Neutral" stateText="{stateText}"
                         texts="{texts}" focused="false" selected="false"
                         highlighted="false" isTitleClickable="false">
            <zoomLevelOneContent>
                <m:HBox height="100%" justifyContent="SpaceBetween" renderType="Bare">
                    <m:Button type="Accept" text="Approve" press="onPress"></m:Button>
                    <m:Button text="Reject" type="Reject"/>
                </m:HBox>
            </zoomLevelOneContent>
        </ProcessFlowNode>
    </nodes>
    <lanes>
        <ProcessFlowLaneHeader laneId="{id}" iconSrc="{icon}" text="{label}" position="{position}"/>
    </lanes>
</ProcessFlow>
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KvtMQ.png)

Answer (score 0):

This feature is not possible with *ProcessFlowNode*. You can use *[nodePress](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/#/api/sap.suite.ui.commons.ProcessFlow%23events/nodePress)* event to open an [*action sheet*](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.m.ActionSheet) or [*popover*](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.m.Popover) for your actions according to your need.

For more information please check:
[Process Flow | SAP Fiori Design Guidelines](https://experience.sap.com/fiori-design-web/process-flow/)

Comment: How we can achieve this by creating custom control?